# How to draw GlyphRun with pixel snapping?

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, directx, rendering

I use `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawGlyphRun` method to render text, but it gets a little blurry. However if I use `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout` method the text comes out very clearly because DirectWrite performs `PixelSnapping`.

So my question is how can I do Pixel Snapping even when I'm using the `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawGlyphRun` method?

I tried to round coordinates:

```
(int)(baselineOrigin.Y + 0.5f)
```

But it only helped in some situations.

What is the correct way to round coordinates before text rendering with Direct2D ?

Thank you very much, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By definition, DrawGlyphRun provides rasterization when you already know the position of the glyphs you want to render. Why can't you use DrawTextLayout (or DirectWrite)? And are you sure you have a pixel snapping issue? Blurryness can have many origins, have you tried playing with ID2D1RenderTarget::SetTextAntialiasMode, ID2D1RenderTarget::SetTextRenderingParams?

Comment: @SimonMourier I can't use `IDWriteTextLayout` because I break lines in a special way and place glyphs in a special way.   And I'm sure the reason is pixel snapping because I used `IDWriteTextRenderer` to extract all `GlyphRun` created by `IDWriteTextLayout`, and I drew `GlyphRun` myself, and it came out blurred. And when I was drew with `IDWriteTextLayout` and with `D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_NO_SNAP` it was also blurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid text blurring, the `Y` position of the glyphs should be rounded. And as you did:

```
(int)(baselineOrigin.Y + 0.5f)
```

But, you should also take into account the `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetTransform`.
If Transform causes a scale other than 1 or causes a vertical shift, you need to calculate the actual location where the glyph will appear and only then round.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't do that with `DrawGlyphRun()`. Pixel snapping mode is conveyed to `IDWriteTextLayout::Draw()` through `IDWriteTextRenderer` that Direct2D implements. `DrawGlyphRun()` does not operate on layout, so you don't have same way to control it.

Regarding coordinate rounding, you probably want to round in horizontal direction for horizontal layout, and your example does not do that.